# Search filtered array indexPath is not correct

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an app which when you use the searchbar filters the patients depending on what you put in though when you click a row it always shows the same data in the next nib file. I know this is because the indexPath is changed as the order of the cells changed and the number of them though is there a way to make it go to the right one?

IndexPath code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    PatientController *patient = [[PatientController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    [delegate.navController pushViewController:patient animated:YES];
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Search code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isFiltered = NO;
    } else {
        isFiltered = YES;

        filteredPatients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (Patient *patient in patients) {
            NSRange patientNameRange = [[patient.patientName substringToIndex:1] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (patientNameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredPatients addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", patient.patientName, patient.patientSurname]];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you please elaborate and show some of the code for index path that you are using?

Comment: @XCodeMonkey have added code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do the filtering you need to refresh the UI (presumably a table view). Now the row information should be taken from the filtered results - this includes the row count, cell content and the cell selection source data. If you refresh and use the correct source of data after the search then everything will match up.

---

Don't pass the `indexPath` around. It's private internal state of your table view controller (and how it can be used is based on the private state about whether a search is in progress). So, get the patient object for the selected row and pass that instead. Something like:

```
Patient *selectedPatient = nil;

if (!isFiltered) {
    selectedPatient = patients[indexPath.row];
} else {
    selectedPatient = filteredPatients[indexPath.row];
}


PatientController *patientController = [[PatientController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];
patientController.patient = selectedPatient;
```

This all goes in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. On `PatientController` you need to remove the `indexPath` property from the .h file and replace it with (or expose publicly) your property for the `patient` that the controller currently gets as a result of the `indexPath`. Then you can delete everything about the `indexPath` from the `PatientController` because you will already have the `patient` instance.

Comment: How does the `PatientController` use the `indexPath`?

Comment: It declares a variable like this: `NSObject *object = [array objectAtIndex:index.row];` then use the object like this: `text1.text = object.name;`

Comment: Ok, so what is the link between `array` in that code and `filteredPatients` in the code from your question?

Comment: Are you saying that I should pass a differnt variable if the array is the filtered array?

Comment: Well, I agree with @atomk that you shouldn't pass the `indexPath` at all. It should be possible to make it work by passing it but you will need to teach `PatientController` more than it already knows (which looks like too much).

Comment: I am using a database so I could pass the id then select from the database

Comment: That would be better as the patient id is more specific and not tied to the table view controller (like the index path is). Would still be better to pass the patient itself though (as you already have it, you don't need to hit the DB).

Comment: I don't get how to use it. I am quite new to ios programming

Comment: How do I call it in my next controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36205/discussion-between-wain-and-ollie-cole)

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is in your implementation of `initWithIndexPath` though i dont know where since you didnt post it.

You need to use the index path to get the data *represented* by the cell by querying into the data structure that is used to populate the table as is currently displayed. So you'd want to query into filteredPatients, but its full of just strings. Fill it with actual patient objects and generate the string when the table asks for the cell.

This is bad design, the patient view controller should have no knowledge of the index path. Use the index path to get the patient then pass it to something like `initWithPatient`

Also, using the app delegate like this is a bad idea. You can access the containing navigation controller with `self.navigationController`

Comment: My app is practically finished so I don't want to go changing it now

Comment: For next time. My main point is, your bug is in that init method so if you want more help you should post it.